# How to write into CSV only once?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm looking the way how to save big files.
Saving the file line by line takes too long time.
How I can build it in memory then save it at once?

```
import csv

file1 = open(r"C:\1.csv")
data1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')

csvfile = open(r"C:\output.csv", 'w', newline='')
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in data1:
    spamwriter.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[3]])
```